# Ratiometric ADC and conversion algorithms

Tags: adc

Let's assume that I want to measure temperature digitally with an MCU. The ADC of the MCU uses successive approximation to convert the analog voltage to digital and I get the 0s and 1s which are converted to digital codes and I can get the temperature from the digital codes. Well this system works fine.

But, because we know that  most of  ADCs are ratio-metric and the digital code of the voltage *Vk* can be calculated from:

$$ \frac{Vk \cdot (2^n-1)}{VDD}$$

Can't we just design a system that calculates the digital code value in ALU of CPU and get the results instead of using SAR and flash in ADCs?

In other words, can we get from the voltage value to the digital code value by calculation instead of going through SAR and then calculate the digital code value?

Comment: And what would be the ADC output then? SAR or sigma-delta are methods to convert analog signal to digital, not just an algorithm with codes that ALU can do it without ADC.

Comment: What I mean is get rid of the ADC altogether, use what we learned from it and calculate the values using ALU. To measure the temperature for example.

Comment: You can't get rid of the ADC.  How will your algorithm know what value to calculate if you don't bring the analog signal into the digital world?

Comment: I am really confused. All I am saying is we can get from the voltage value to the digital code value by calculation instead of going through SAR and then calculate the digital code value.

Comment: @MaryE No, you can't.

Comment: Your question does not contain a complete question. If you know what the Voltage Vk IS you can calculate the corresponding digital code. And if you know a digital code you can calculate what the voltage that would produce it would be if you know the details of the system that produced it. But you seem to be making some unstated and incorrect assumptions. | Imagine you have an ALU and an analog voltage. You want to know what value the voltage corresponds to on a scale of say 0 to 255 where 255 = Max Voltage possible and 0 = zero volts. To calculate the code you MUST know the voltage ...

Comment: ... To achieve this you need some way of determining what the voltage is - and that is waht an ADC does. Once you know the voltage you can calculate the code OR in an SAR system the code is produced as an integral part opf the system process. **QUESTION**: How do you propose that an unknown  voltage  becomes known if you do not use an ADC to measure it? And ADC is just "a voltmeter for a computer". If YOU have an unknow boltage you would need to use a meter to measure it. A computer also must use a "meter" - which we call an ADC. OIf that does not make sense please explain why not in DETAIL .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ADC is converting an analogue signal (voltage level) into a digital code, that represents the analogue voltage.

ALU's are implemented with digital logic that only understands 'high' and 'low' voltage levels.

We need additional analogue circuitry to compare an arbitrary input voltage with some other known voltages in order to convert the voltage level into a digital code. That is what an ADC is. The ways that can be done include successive approximation, flash, tracking, time to charge a capacitor and lots of others, but an ALU simply cant.

Comment: Please let me know if I get it right. So we need a digital representation of Vk to do the calculation in ALU and therefore we need the ADC otherwise ALU won't be able to do the calculation.

Comment: Yes. ALU's can only work with digital (numbers represented as a series of 1's and 0's) representations of things.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are horribly confused and using the wrong terms, but I think I see what you are trying to ask.

You apply a voltage to the ADC input, and your MCU receives a code that indicates the portion of the ADC range.

Say, you have a 12 bit ADC that can accept a voltage from 0 to 3.0 volts.  If you apply 3.0 Volts to the ADC input, then the ADC will give a numeric value of 4095 to the MCU.

What you are asking is:  Why can't the ADC report a numeric value of 3.0 instead of 4095?

Well, you could make one that does that.  It would be very complicated on the inside, though, since it would have to deal with either binary coded digits (BCD) or floating point numbers.  It would also have to communicate the numbers to your MCU in that format.

So, you would go from a 12 bit binary representation to a 32 Bit (floating point) or possibly more bits (BCD) to represent the same value.  That requires more time to communicate from the ADC to the MCU, so you are slowing things down to no gain.  Your MCU would have to under stand the format the ADC sends, and convert it internally to something it can use - and many smaller MCUs can't natively handle floating point and will need a large library to work with those numbers.  Same applies to BCD.

Next is that many ADCs operate from a reference voltage that can be changed from out side - the ADC has no idea what reference it is using.  It would have to be able to measure that and make some kind of sense out of it to do the calculation.

So, you are asking why the ADC doesn't do a simple step (binary value to voltage value) for you to simplify your software, when doing that simple step (in software) turns out to be an enormous mess in hardware.

Simple reason:  Could be done, but isn't needed and it would be complex, expensive, and slower than what is normally used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you understand what an ADC converter is!

The nearest we can get to what you're asking for is a sigma delta converter. It still uses an ADC, but it's a one bit ADC. It needs a filter wrapping round it, but it does give you probably the least total analogue complexity for an ADC, and yes, given the bit stream that comes from it, you have to calculate the final answer in the ALU.

Unfortunately the wikipedia article on delta sigma is a bit misleading, so I won't link to it.

These tutorials from Maxim and TI are somewhat better

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/1870

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt423/slyt423.pdf

Comment: I am really confused. All I am saying is we can get from the voltage value to the digital code value by calculation instead of going through SAR and then calculate the digital code value

Comment: So 'out there', in the real analogue world, we have a 1.5v battery, and in the ALU, we have registers and adders controlled by a program. So how are you going to let the ALU 'see' the volts on the terminals? I'm confused by your confusion. If somebody tells the program that the battery voltage is 1.5v, and the rail voltage is 5v, so CONST batt_volts = 1.5; CONST VDD = 5.0; then the ALU can work it out. But if the programmer doesn't provide those CONSTs, how will the ALU find out what the battery voltage is? By reading an ADC, successive approximation, sigma delta, or whatever.

Comment: This indeed a good tech answer (so you have my upovote), but the OP had a much more basic confusion. Also (@Mary E should) note that the Maxim note is far too abrupt for an intro to this (delta-sigma) topic. The TI one looks more gentle.

Answer (score 0):

When you measure the temperature, you use a sensor. Converting the [analog] voltage or current from that sensor, into a digital value, is the job of the ADC.

*Formatting* the 1's and 0's afterwards can be done with the CPU. Are you measuring degrees Celsius? Do you want *negative* values for sub-zero temperatures?

Do you want to calibrate, for accurate readings? Place the sensor in a glass, filled with fresh water and ice: the reading you get is the setting for "zero Celsius". A pot of boiling water on a stove will get you "100 Celsius". Taking all those calibration factors into account, to provide an accurate reading, is where the CPU processing power comes into play.